# Android studio error cause invalid distance too far back

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Every time I try to run my code or create a new project on android studio I keep getting this error

> Caused by: java.util.zip.ZipException: invalid distance too far back

and I've tried reinstalling android studio, reinstalling my gradle, and more.

- Windows 10,
- Java version 1.8
- Android studio version 3.3

Answer (score 0):

This mostly happens when your jar file is corrupted or not able to unzip. Check your jar file.

Comment: Thank you very much for the reply but where exactly can I find this jar file you speak of? And how will I know if it's corrupted. Please help.

Comment: Or should I delete my previous Java and download another one???

Comment: try reinstalling java